# In QT5 I need to create at least 20 QThread

Tags: c++, qt5

In *QT5* I need to create at least 20 threads.
What should be the method?
Currently I am using `QtConcurrent::run` to create threads but only four of them are running at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately there is nothing magic behind `QtConcurrent` and threads, so *logically running at a time* usually differs from *actually running at a time* and you cannot expect to see `N` of them running at a time for each `N`, if only because either you have `M` cores on your machine or you rely on a thread pool under the hood.

In particular, if you look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) of `QtConcurrent`, you find that:

> QtConcurrent automatically adjust the number of threads used according to the number of processor cores available.

About the [`run`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run) member method you find for:

```
QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::run(Function function, ...)
```

That it's equivalent to:

```
 QtConcurrent::run(QThreadPool::globalInstance(), function, ...);
```

In fact, it states that it:

> Runs *function* in a separate thread. The thread is taken from the global QThreadPool. Note that *function* may not run immediately; *function* will only be run once a thread becomes available.

You can see the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html) of `QThreadPool` for further details.
In particular, it's interesting the member method `idealThreadCount`, the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#idealThreadCount) of which states that:

> Returns the ideal number of threads that can be run on the system. This is done querying the number of processor cores, both real and logical, in the system.

Please, note also that you can ever [set the maximum number of threads used by the thread pool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#maxThreadCount-prop) by means of the member method `setMaxThreadCount` of the `QThreadPool`.

That's all, quite easy and we'll documented indeed.
Because of that, you have actually no guarantees that your threads will run all together at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Feel free to accept it if you don't want further details, so that the question will be considered closed.

Comment: But I need to run a lot of continuous running lightweight processes . like running ffmpeg to copy a video device to another on linux machine.

Comment: It doesn't mean that they won't run, it means that they will run when it makes sense to spawn them. Even if you have 20 threads running on a 4 core, how can you actually execute more than 4 of them at a time? Well, it's a bit more complex, but maybe you got the idea...

Comment: yes.. If I run more than 5 threads from a C program , it runs all of them interchangeably , I know that it will need scheduling. I am trying to achieve the same in Qt but after four threads , it does not schedule any other ...

Comment: Because the thread pool sets its max count on the number of processors. I've updated the answer, try using `setMaxThreadCount` on the global thread pool or a locally created one.